# Idiorm query count

Tags: php, mysql, database, orm, idiorm

**Count queries**

A long time ago I think I was able to count the total queries made on a page with [idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/).

Now I can't find out how it's done. Any reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can request the value of the session's [`Questions`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Questions) status variable:

```php
$questions = ORM::for_table(null)
                ->raw_query('SHOW STATUS LIKE ?', ['Questions'])
                ->find_one()
                ['Value'];
```